# C# X509Certificate2: Where to store the private key?

Tags: windows, wcf, store, private-key, x509certificate2

I have a self-hosted WCF application, which acts as a server and I want to install/deploy it on a Windows machine.

The application uses a self-signed certificate, which I created with makecert.exe. So the PFX, CER and PVK are there and available. Everything works fine.

At this point of time and only for testing, the application reads the certificate and the private key from an embedded resource. That means both are compiled into the application, which is a high security risk.

I already know, that the most common way to store this data, is the windows certificate store. And I also know, how to save and read from the windows certificate store.

But there is something, that I still do not get:

**Where do I store the private key (PVK) for the certificate (CER), so that my application is able to use the CER?**

I mean, if my application can read it, then anybody, who has access to this machine, can read it. Or is this wrong?

Do I have to take care myself or is there any "industry standard" for windows machines, to save and read the PVK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows certificate store is the most common place to store certificates (i.e. CA) or certificates with private key (End entity).

If you store certificate ( with private key - PFX) in **LocalMachine\My** store then you can assign privileges who (what account) can access private key. It is done through **certlm.msc** tool. System account has access by default so any system service can use the private key.

There are other ways to store private key (like smartcard, HSM, net HSM etc.) and other ways to access private key (like PKCS#11).

Comment: Thank you, pepo. If you say "account", you mean Windows account, don't you? So the software has to run under the "system account" or under the account, under which the software has been installed. Are there any ways, that only the software can access the private key? For example, through another password or another secret?

Comment: Yes, account=windows account. I don't know of a way that would grant access only to this application and no other. Well, if you use PKCS#11 to access the private key, there is a login password. You can start the application with this password and only that application will have access to the private key. But using PKCS#11 means that you have to implement almost all by yourself.

Comment: `only the software can access the private key` -- software is not a security boundary. For your goal you will have to keep the key within the software.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thank you Crypt32. I know, every (!) software, even native code, can be decompiled and reverse engineered, if someone is able and willing to do that. Do you have any suggestions, to make it very hard and tiring for an attacker, to read the private key from an assembly? From a feeling, not from knowing, it seems to me, that the Windows certificate store is not the safest place to store the private key. If someone is able to hack a server, he is probably also able to read the private keys from the certificate store. Any links to sources, how to hide a secret in an assembly are welcome!

Comment: @Michael - an assembly is actually the worst place to try to hide something, because it's the easiest to get access to (so many copies).  "Hack a server" has different levels of access, some of which may not grant key access.  Note that solving this problem is often why dedicated reverse proxies are used, usually with CA issued (not self-signed)  certs.  There _are_ hardware-only, enterprise grade solutions, but usually have enterprise grade prices to match.